# Correct Content-Type for a webhook I'm sending using POST

Tags: json, http, http-headers, webhooks

I'm working on a platform that sends webhooks for several events.

We're sending a JSON string as the value of the `payload` parameter in a POST request to the user defined webhook URL.

For the `Content-Type` header should we be using:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or
- `application/json`

The JSON object can contain any (UTF-8 encoded) unicode string including custom data served beforehand by the user, so we're not controlling it.

Comment: Hey, I just came across [one of your edit suggestions](/review/suggested-edits/20248397), which added a link to your company's website. That's a very risky edit; it's very close to being [spam](/help/promotion), even though you aren't linking to a product. Be very cautious when linking to your own (or your company's) website. When adding a reference to somebody else's post, I would recommend using a source that you aren't affiliated with (if you can find a good one). Cheers!

Comment: @AndrewMyers You are right. I have [updated (and corrected)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20260337) my edit and changed the source to a [Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc).

Answer (score 0):

If your payload is indeed JSON, then "application/json" (or somethiing more specific) is the right media type to specify.

Comment: Since the body of the request is `payload={"version":"1.0","event":"recorded"}` which doesn't validate as JSON because of `payload=` I'm more inclined to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Well, in that case the payload is a form type, not JSON.